# strptime_l returning null

Tags: objective-c, c, strptime, time.h

`strptime_l` is always returning null. I'm doing this in Objective-C.

```
#import <time.h>
#import <xlocale.h>

/* Later on... */      

    const char *str = [dateStr UTF8String];
    const char *fmt = [@"EE LLLL d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" UTF8String];
    struct tm timeinfo;
    memset(&timeinfo, 0, sizeof(timeinfo));
    char *ret = strptime_l(str, fmt, &timeinfo, NULL);

    NSDate *date = nil;

    if (ret) {
        time_t time = mktime(&timeinfo);

        date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:time];
    }
```

`ret` is always null. An example of `dateStr`'s value is: `Sat Sep 15 05:52:10 +0000 2012` and is always in that format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the NSDateFormatter format instead of the strptime one. Take a look [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strptime.html) for more info its specific date and time format.

The following code should work:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Sat Sep 15 05:52:10 +0000 2012";

const char *str = [dateStr UTF8String];
const char *fmt = [@"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y" UTF8String];
struct tm timeinfo;
memset(&timeinfo, 0, sizeof(timeinfo));
char *ret = strptime_l(str, fmt, &timeinfo, NULL);

NSDate *date = nil;

if (ret) {
    time_t time = mktime(&timeinfo);

    date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:time];
}
```

By the way you could have achieved the same by simply doing:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Sat Sep 15 05:52:10 +0000 2012";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE LLLL d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I was using `NSDateFormatter` before but `strptime_l` appears to be faster and is more suited in my situation. I forgot about the different formatting.